# Cannot copy from a TensorFlowLite tensor (StatefulPartitionedCall:0) with shape [1, 25200, 14] to a Java object with shape [1, 9]

Tags: flutter, dart, machine-learning, deep-learning, tflite

I am using flutter to create an app to detect objects, recognize faces,..etc
I get error when using tflite package to integrate my custom model with the app

here is the source code

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:tflite/tflite.dart';

class Tensorflow extends StatefulWidget {
  const Tensorflow({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _TensorflowState createState() => _TensorflowState();
}

class _TensorflowState extends State<Tensorflow> {
  List? _outputs;
  File? _image;
  bool _loading = false;
  double? _imageWidth;
  double? _imageHeight;
  List? _recognitions;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _loading = true;

    loadModel().then((value) {
      setState(() {
        _loading = false;
      });
    });
  }

  loadModel() async {
    try {
      await Tflite.loadModel(
        model: "assets/best-fp16.tflite",
        labels: "assets/data.txt",
      );
    } on PlatformException {
      print("Failed to load the model");
    }
  }

  classifyImage(File image) async {
    print("classifyImage running");
    var output = await Tflite.runModelOnImage(
      path: image.path,
    );
    FileImage(image)
        .resolve(ImageConfiguration())
        .addListener((ImageStreamListener((ImageInfo info, bool _) {
          setState(() {
            _imageWidth = info.image.width.toDouble();
            _imageHeight = info.image.height.toDouble();
          });
        })));
    print("output = ");
    print(output);

    if (output!.isEmpty) {
      print("in if output = []");
      var tmp = {
        "confidence": 0,
        "index": 100,
        "label": "Can't identify",
      };
      output = [...output, tmp];
      print("output after change in if = ");
      print(output);
    }

    setState(() {
      _loading = false;
      _outputs = output;
    });

    print("_outputs = ");
    print(_outputs);

    print("classifyImage set state complete");
    print(
        "==============================================================================");
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    Tflite.close();
  }

  pickImage() async {
    print(
        "==============================================================================");
    var image = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    if (image == null) {
      print("image is null");
      return null;
    }
    setState(() {
      _loading = true;
      _image = File(image.path);
    });
    classifyImage(_image!);
  }

  List<Widget> renderBoxes(Size screen) {
    if (_recognitions == null) return [];
    if (_imageWidth == null || _imageHeight == null) return [];

    double factorX = screen.width;
    double factorY = _imageHeight! / _imageHeight! * screen.width;

    Color blue = Colors.red;

    return _recognitions!.map((re) {
      return Positioned(
        left: re["rect"]["x"] * factorX,
        top: re["rect"]["y"] * factorY,
        width: re["rect"]["w"] * factorX,
        height: re["rect"]["h"] * factorY,
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border.all(
            color: blue,
            width: 3,
          )),
          child: Text(
            "${re["detectedClass"]} ${(re["confidenceInClass"] * 100).toStringAsFixed(0)}%",
            style: TextStyle(
              background: Paint()..color = blue,
              color: Colors.white,
              fontSize: 15,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }).toList();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        title: const Text(
          'Fruits and Veggies Neural Network',
          style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w200,
              fontSize: 20,
              letterSpacing: 0.8),
        ),
      ),
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.9),
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 35, vertical: 50),
        child: Container(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: const Color(0xFF2A363B),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
          ),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Container(
                child: Center(
                  child: _loading == true
                      ? null //show nothing if no picture selected
                      : Container(
                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              Container(
                                height: 250,
                                width: 250,
                                child: ClipRRect(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                                  child: _image == null
                                      ? Container(
                                          height: 50,
                                          width: double.infinity,
                                          color: Colors.amber,
                                        )
                                      : Image.file(_image!),
                                ),
                              ),
                              const Divider(
                                height: 25,
                                thickness: 1,
                              ),
                              _outputs != null
                                  ? Text(
                                      'The object is: ${_outputs![0]['label']}!',
                                      style: const TextStyle(
                                          color: Colors.white,
                                          fontSize: 18,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                                    )
                                  : Container(),
                              const Divider(
                                height: 25,
                                thickness: 1,
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 30,
                    ),
                    GestureDetector(
                      onTap: pickImage, //no parenthesis
                      child: Container(
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 200,
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                            horizontal: 24, vertical: 17),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.blueGrey[600],
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
                        child: const Text(
                          'Pick From Gallery',
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and this is the error that I get and then the app crashes

```
I/InterpreterApi(19420): Loaded native library: tensorflowlite_jni
I/InterpreterApi(19420): Didn't load native library: tensorflowlite_jni_gms_client
I/tflite  (19420): Initialized TensorFlow Lite runtime.
W/ithub_tfliteapp(19420): type=1400 audit(0.0:42592): avc: denied { read } for name="u:object_r:vendor_default_prop:s0" dev="tmpfs" ino=12923 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c39,c257,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:vendor_default_prop:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
E/libc    (19420): Access denied finding property "ro.hardware.chipname"
I/tflite  (19420): Created TensorFlow Lite XNNPACK delegate for CPU.
W/Gralloc3(19420): mapper 3.x is not supported
I/tflite  (19420): Replacing 486 node(s) with delegate (TfLiteXNNPackDelegate) node, yielding 7 partitions.
W/Looper  (19420): Slow Looper main: Long Msg: seq=351 plan=١٦:٥٧:١٦.٨٥٣  late=9ms wall=2801ms running=559ms runnable=38ms io=2084ms reclaim=2ms h=android.os.Handler c=io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.-$$Lambda$DartMessenger$TsixYUB5E6FpKhMtCSQVHKE89gQ
I/Choreographer(19420): Skipped 169 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
I/OpenGLRenderer(19420): Davey! duration=3058ms; Flags=0, IntendedVsync=72247862129103, Vsync=72250678795657, OldestInputEvent=9223372036854775807, NewestInputEvent=0, HandleInputStart=72250684016756, AnimationStart=72250684150818, PerformTraversalsStart=72250684258006, DrawStart=72250709874256, SyncQueued=72250832948527, SyncStart=72250833268631, IssueDrawCommandsStart=72250834512433, SwapBuffers=72250917023891, FrameCompleted=72250920814308, DequeueBufferDuration=7374000, QueueBufferDuration=2793000,
W/Looper  (19420): Slow Looper main: doFrame is 2821ms late because of 1 msg, msg 1 took 2801ms (seq=351 running=559ms runnable=38ms io=2084ms reclaim=2ms late=9ms h=android.os.Handler c=io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.-$$Lambda$DartMessenger$TsixYUB5E6FpKhMtCSQVHKE89gQ)
I/flutter (19420): ==============================================================================
I/Timeline(19420): Timeline: Activity_launch_request time:72255028
W/ActivityThread(19420): SCHED: com.example.github_tfliteapp/.MainActivity [90, r=1030ms, a=108ms, w=13052ms]
W/System  (19420): A resource failed to call close.
W/Activity(19420): Slow Operation: Activity com.example.github_tfliteapp/.MainActivity onActivityResult took 236ms
I/flutter (19420): classifyImage running
E/AndroidRuntime(19420): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
E/AndroidRuntime(19420): Process: com.example.github_tfliteapp, PID: 19420
E/AndroidRuntime(19420): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
E/AndroidRuntime(19420):    at android.os.AsyncTask$4.done(AsyncTask.java:399)
E/AndroidRuntime(19420):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:383)
E/AndroidRuntime(19420):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:252)
E/AndroidRuntime(19420):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:271)
E/AndroidRuntime(19420):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:289)
E/AndroidRuntime(19420):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
E/AndroidRuntime(19420):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
E/AndroidRuntime(19420):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
E/AndroidRuntime(19420): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot copy from a TensorFlowLite tensor (StatefulPartitionedCall:0) with shape [1, 25200, 14] to a Java object with shape [1, 9].
E/AndroidRuntime(19420):    at org.tensorflow.lite.TensorImpl.throwIfDstShapeIsIncompatible(TensorImpl.java:456)
E/AndroidRuntime(19420):    at org.tensorflow.lite.TensorImpl.copyTo(TensorImpl.java:215)
E/AndroidRuntime(19420):    at org.tensorflow.lite.NativeInterpreterWrapper.run(NativeInterpreterWrapper.java:263)
E/AndroidRuntime(19420):    at org.tensorflow.lite.InterpreterImpl.runForMultipleInputsOutputs(InterpreterImpl.java:133)
E/AndroidRuntime(19420):    at org.tensorflow.lite.Interpreter.runForMultipleInputsOutputs(Interpreter.java:80)
E/AndroidRuntime(19420):    at org.tensorflow.lite.InterpreterImpl.run(InterpreterImpl.java:126)
E/AndroidRuntime(19420):    at org.tensorflow.lite.Interpreter.run(Interpreter.java:80)
E/AndroidRuntime(19420):    at sq.flutter.tflite.TflitePlugin$RunModelOnImage.runTflite(TflitePlugin.java:504)
E/AndroidRuntime(19420):    at sq.flutter.tflite.TflitePlugin$TfliteTask.doInBackground(TflitePlugin.java:471)
E/AndroidRuntime(19420):    at sq.flutter.tflite.TflitePlugin$TfliteTask.doInBackground(TflitePlugin.java:445)
E/AndroidRuntime(19420):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.call(AsyncTask.java:378)
E/AndroidRuntime(19420):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
E/AndroidRuntime(19420):    ... 4 more
W/ActivityThread(19420): SCHED: com.example.github_tfliteapp/.MainActivity [92, r=392ms, a=30ms, w=5356ms]
I/Process (19420): Sending signal. PID: 19420 SIG: 9
Lost connection to device.
```

I think there is a problem with the shape but I can't handle this problem
can any one help?
thanks.